# Shape Border In Android

Tags: android

How can I draw a rectangle that have a black border and white background? I don't understand shape tags in xml! Both solid and stroke do same thing? please let me understand.

Comment: [See this](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-custom-dialog-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shapes to make the white rectangle you need and Stroke to get  the black border you require  . Define a xml for this in your drawables  folder and use .
Refer to this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape